# Как избавиться от вложенного массива data при передаче Api Resource во вью компонент с помощью Inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertia

Я использую Laravel 9, Jetstream, Inertia, Vue 3.

Я создал АПИ ресурс для модель Project и пытаюсь их получить во ВЬЮ компоненте с помощью Инерции.

```
$projects = ProjectResource::collection(Project::get());

return Inertia::render('Project/Edit', compact('projects'));
```

В Vue в пропсе «project» я получаю вложенный массив «data», и в нем уже проекты.

```
projects: 
data:Array[2]
0:Object
1:Object
```

Но это неправильно. Мне не нужен вложенный массив data. Мне сразу нужны модели в пропсе, как это передается во вью без использования Инерции. Т.е. должно быть так

```
projects:
0:Object
1:Object
```

Я не хочу получать доступ в vue через «projects.data»
Как добиться нормальной передачи данных используя апи ресурсы?

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано решение [Laravel Resources API](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping)
Нужно прописать JsonResource::withoutWrapping(); в провайдере

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык